# How to login through external API generate JWT?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-middleware

I have an external API which include login service and generate JWT what I need connect my asp.net core application with this external login service to sign in through generated token

```
try
{
                // validate user name and password
                loginInfo = await service.LoginAsync(loginUrl, userName, password);


                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(loginInfo.Token);
                returnTo = returnUrl;
                success = true;
            }
            catch (Exception httpEx)
            {

            }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which OIDC/OAuth Server are you using? You have far to little information to give you any concrete answer

Comment: I'm using external Auth server depend on OAuth 2.0 and loginInfo.Token give me a generated token what I need is using this token in my asp.net core app to signin.let me know if you need more information

Comment: But `HttpContext.SignInAsync` expects a `ClaimsPrincipal` or claims in most of its overloads. How did you expect that to work with a token we even don't know how it looks?

Comment: Can you provide me with a sample which explain how to use external service which generate JWT with asp.net core application to signin?

Comment: probably this question help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249428/transfer-jwt-authentication-implementation-from-net-core-2-to-asp-net-web-api-2

Answer (score 0):

Try this to call external API to get token and use that in your project

```
public class Wrapper
{
    string baseUrl = string.Empty;
    string token = string.Empty;

    public Wrapper()
    {
        this.baseUrl = "your url";
    }

    public async Task<object> GetToken(string username, string password)
    {
        string Url = "/api/Token/Get";
        object body = null;

            body = new
            {
                Username = username,
                Password = password
            };

        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                HttpResponseMessage Response = await client.PostAsync(Url, new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).ConfigureAwait(false);
                if (Response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var result = Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(JObject.Parse(result).Property("error").Value.ToString()))
                    {
                        token = JObject.Parse(result).Property("access_token").Value.ToString();
                        return token;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       return string.Empty;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```