# transfer JWT Authentication implementation from .net core 2 to asp.net web api 2

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api2, jwt, owin

i have implementation of **JWT Authentication** in **.net core 2 application**, it work fine.

i want to use this implementation and structure in **asp.net web api 2** application but i get error

**my structure:**

*JwtTokenBuilder class:*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Linq;

namespace solution.Authentication
{
  public sealed class JwtTokenBuilder
  {
    private SecurityKey securityKey = null;
    private string subject = "";
    private string issuer = "";
    private string audience = "";
    private Dictionary<string, string> claims = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    private DateTime expireTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30);

    public JwtTokenBuilder AddSecurityKey(SecurityKey securityKey)
    {
      this.securityKey = securityKey;
      return this;
    }

    public JwtTokenBuilder AddSubject(string subject)
    {
      this.subject = subject;
      return this;
    }

    public JwtTokenBuilder AddIssuer(string issuer)
    {
      this.issuer = issuer;
      return this;
    }

    public JwtTokenBuilder AddAudience(string audience)
    {
      this.audience = audience;
      return this;
    }

    public JwtTokenBuilder AddClaim(string type, string value)
    {
      this.claims.Add(type, value);
      return this;
    }

    public JwtTokenBuilder AddClaims(Dictionary<string, string> claims)
    {
      this.claims.Union(claims);
      return this;
    }

    public JwtTokenBuilder AddExpiry(DateTime expireTime)
    {
      this.expireTime = expireTime;
      return this;
    }

    public JwtToken Build()
    {
      EnsureArguments();

      var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
              new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, this.subject),
              new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
            }
      .Union(this.claims.Select(item => new Claim(item.Key, item.Value)));

      var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                        issuer: this.issuer,
                        audience: this.audience,
                        claims: claims,
                        expires: this.expireTime,
                        signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(
                                                  this.securityKey,
                                                  SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256));

      return new JwtToken(token);
    }

    #region " private "

    private void EnsureArguments()
    {
      if (this.securityKey == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Security Key");

      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.subject))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Subject");

      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.issuer))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Issuer");

      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.audience))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Audience");
    }

    #endregion
  }
}
```

*token Object:*

```
using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;

namespace solution.Authentication
{
  public sealed class JwtToken
  {
    private JwtSecurityToken token;

    internal JwtToken(JwtSecurityToken token)
    {
      this.token = token;
    }

    public DateTime ValidTo => token.ValidTo;
    public string access_token => new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(this.token);
  }
}
```

*security key class:*

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;

namespace solution.Authentication
{
  public static class JwtSecurityKey
  {
    public static SymmetricSecurityKey Create(string secret)
    {
      return new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secret));
    }
  }
}
```

my token controller methode for *generate* and return *token* :

```
private JwtToken getToken(User user)
{
  DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
  DateTime expireTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60);

  var token = new JwtTokenBuilder()
                 .AddSecurityKey(JwtSecurityKey.Create("SecurityKey"))
                 .AddSubject("Subject")
                 .AddIssuer("Issuer")
                 .AddAudience("Audience")
                 .AddClaim("Username", user.UserName)
                 .AddExpiry(expireTime)
                 .Build();

  return token;
}
```

in .net core 2 application i use **OWIN** Startup class to **validate** my **token** for all controllers which have **Authorize** attribute.

*controller example:*

```
namespace solution.Controllers
{
  public class ExampleController : ApiController
  {
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Example")]
    [Authorize(Policy = "Session")]
    public void Run()
    {
       // do something;
    }
  }  
}
```

my owin startup class for validating JWT token :

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace solution
{
  public class Startup
  {
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
               .AddJwtBearer(options =>
               {
                 options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                 {
                   ValidateIssuer = true,
                   ValidateAudience = true,
                   ValidateLifetime = true,
                   ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

                   ValidIssuer = "Issuer",
                   ValidAudience = "Audience",
                   IssuerSigningKey = JwtSecurityKey.Create("SecurityKey")



                 };

                 options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                 {
                   OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                   {
                     return Task.CompletedTask;
                   },
                   OnTokenValidated = context =>
                   {
                     return Task.CompletedTask;
                   }
                 };
               });

      services.AddAuthorization(options =>
      {
        options.AddPolicy("Session", policy => policy.RequireClaim("SessionId"));
      });

      services.AddSignalR();
      services.AddCors(options =>
      {
        options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
            builder => builder
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());
      });
      services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
      loggerFactory.AddConsole();

      if (env.IsDevelopment())
      {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
      }

      app.Use(async (context, next) =>
      {
        await next();
        if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 &&
            !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value) &&
            !context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
          context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
          await next();
        }
      });

      app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
      app.UseAuthentication();
      app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
      app.UseDefaultFiles();
      app.UseStaticFiles();
      app.UseCors(policyName: "CorsPolicy");
      app.UseSignalR(routes =>
      {
      });
    }
  }
}
```

i want to use this structure in **asp.net web api** only change **owin** class, it's possible?
please help me for any change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

structure change for transfer my implementation from **.net core 2** to **asp.net web api 2**

i use `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` namespace for generate and validate JWT token.

.net core 2 compatible with `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt version="5.1.4"` but asp.net web api 2 compatible with `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt version="4.0.2"`

The same change in the package version made changes to the code, also the part of code i use the `System.IdentityModel.Tokens` namespace instead of `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens` because of changing package versions.

**code changes:**

*JwtTokenBuilder class:*

in this class change `SigningCredentials` parameter setting

```
  var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                    issuer: this.issuer,
                    audience: this.audience,
                    claims: claims,
                    expires: this.expireTime,
                    signingCredentials: new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials(
                                              this.securityKey,
                                              Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature
                                            , Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature));
```

*security key class:*

change the security key generation method

```
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Text;

namespace solution.Authentication
{
  public static class JwtSecurityKey
  {
    public static SymmetricSecurityKey Create(string secret)
    {
      return new InMemorySymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret));
    }
  }
}
```

*controller attribute:*

```
namespace solution.Controllers
{
  public class ExampleController : ApiController
  {
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Example")]
    [System.Web.Http.Authorize]
    public void Run()
    {
       // do something;
    }
  }  
}
```

My main change was in **Startup OWIN** class and change `Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt` package version from "3.1.0" to "3.0.0" for validate JWT token for incoming requests.

*implementation:*

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using System.Web.Http;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(solution.Startup))]

namespace solution
{
  public class Startup
  {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
      app.MapSignalR();
      HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
      config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
      ConfigureOAuth(app);
      app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
      app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
    public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
      var issuer = "issuer";
      var audience = "audience";
      var secret = JwtSecurityKey.Create("SecurityKey").GetSymmetricKey();

      // Api controllers with an [Authorize] attribute will be validated with JWT
      var option =
          new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
          {
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            AllowedAudiences = new[] { audience },
            IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
              {
                        new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, secret)
              }
          };
      app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
            option
        );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you get `IssuerSecurityTokenProviders`? I only have `IssuerSecurityKeyProviders`.