# How to login with Identity using JWT?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

I have implemented JWT and an authentication web api and now I'm trying to connect my front end (which is created using ASP.NET Core) to it.

I have used the scaffolded Identity login page.

This is how I request for a JWT:

```
public interface IAuthenticationClient
{
    string Authenticate(LoginViewModel Input);
}

public class AuthenticationClient : IAuthenticationClient
{
    private readonly string baseAddress = "http://localhost:55260/api/Accounts/";

    public AuthenticationClient()
    {

    }

    public string Authenticate(LoginViewModel Input)
    {
        try
        {
            var client = new RestClient(baseAddress + "Authenticate");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            request.AddBody(new { Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.SecretKey });
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            return response.Content;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I know that I can save the token into a cookie but how can I use the token with the signinmanager to let the app know that i've signed in?

This is the scaffolded identity login that is located in the application that calls the API

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
        if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
        }
        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
            return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
            return Page();
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return Page();
}
```

Comment: this question may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48249428/transfer-jwt-authentication-implementation-from-net-core-2-to-asp-net-web-api-2

Comment: Please don't put useless tags in question titles. I've removed them from your questions over and over again.

Comment: You want get the token in the application that calls the API, i.e. the angular application (if you use Angular SPAs), your mobile app etc. Then you pass the JWT token in the `Authentication` head as bearer token, like `Authentication: Bearer <base64 of your JWT token>` and then use call to the `services.AddAuthentication().AddJwtBearer(...)`

Comment: Also check [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto sorry, with the tags is it not c#, .net core and jwt? Also, the Page is in another .net core application that calls the api.

Comment: @Tseng I am not using angular. I am using .net core and I want to login using jwt instead of the typical passwordsigninasync

Comment: You are using ASP.NET Core, .NET Core is not relevant here.

Comment: You don't use a JWT to *sign-in* - a JWT is essentially just proof that you are *already* signed in.

Comment: What is your front end built in? For Angular for example use something like OIDC Client to get a token, and pass that in the headers (HttpInjector)...

Comment: @AustinTFrench I'm using .net core as well.

Comment: @KirkLarkin but is it possible to combine it with something like the signinmanager or passwordsignin to let the front end know that I have signed in?

Comment: To make this clear: the OP has an ASP.NET Core Razor Pages front-end and wants to authenticate to an ASP.NET Core Web API back-end using JWT

Comment: Yeah, sorry for not making this clear.

Comment: @JianYA: Yea, but the JWT is passed **ON EACH REQUEST**. The JWT **IS** the proof that the user is authenticated. You can validate its expiration, audience (is the JWT really issued for this service?) and it's signature. When the signature is valid, the user is authenticated. ASP.NET Core Identity is not required, thats the whole point of JWT. Its self-contained and no need to validate against a database, just validate signature and token itself

Comment: @Tseng I am pretty sure the OP just wants to use `[Authorize]` after they obtained the JWT from the back-end

Comment: @Tseng I think I'm getting it now. So instead of relying on Identity, I just rely on sending my token across for each request and on each page, I just need to check if I have a valid token? If thats the case, I can create my own [Authorize] filter as well.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: I think he misunderstands what JWT is for, since in his example code he wants to use it as sign in manager. But JWT isn't used to authenticate against Razor/MVC pages (well, one could register using external OIDC providers such as google, facebook etc, sign in the user (without password, just his id) and then set up a cookie. That's how authentication on MVC works.

Comment: @Tseng Yeah, I'm aware of that, the OP is confused though

Comment: @JianYA: When you have WebAPI yes. MVC/Razor pages are best authenticated with external OpenIDConnect (or OAuth) providers, such as Facebook & Co. There is a `_signInManager.SignInAsync` (not `_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync`) call in Identity to let you log in a user without a password. You do that usually in callback, after the user has authenticated with google and then its posted back to your application, you validate the response (i.e. from google and if its valid) then use that to login the user (again: without password, the external authentication acts as password in this case)

Comment: `_signInManager.SignInAsync` also sets the authentication cookie for the user (you can't pass authentication headers in MVC/Razor pages, thats why you need cookies there)

Comment: @Tseng I see. Thank you. I will make changes to my application based on what you said. Thanks for taking the time to explain it to me.